why DOMPDF has a strange behaviour with position absolute especially after the 3 version release?
i noticed a strange behaviour with dompdf version 3 relatively to absolute positioning of an element inside a container relatively positioned. I will give a very simple example so everyone can understand what i am talking about.
<div class="container" style="position:relative;"> 
     <img style="width:100%;height:100%;">
     <img style="position:absolute;width:100px;height:100px;bottom:10px;left:0px;">
 </div>

Before passing to 3 version of DOMPDF the second image was absolutely positioned relatively to the container.The first img you are seeing was an image used as a background for the first page of the PDF i was generating.
After DOMPDF 3 update i decided to see if the PDF was still good and i saw something incredibly strange. There was a white space under the img used as a background.
After some tries to return to the original PDF shape i simply changed the order of the elements and the white space was gone. Can someone tell me why this happened and if there is better documentation on this problem about DOMPDF?
<div class="container" style="position:relative;"> 
     <img style="position:absolute;width:100px;height:100px;bottom:10px;left:0px;">
     <img style="width:100%;height:100%;">
</div>

